# How to convert byte array of multipart/form-data request body into String in Java?

Tags: java, http, spring-webflux, multipartform-data

I have a request body, content-type is multipart/form data, body is like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxx

--xxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"

<content of file>
--xxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text1"

text value
...
```

It comes to my method as `byte[] body`. I create a String from it: `new String(body, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` divide this String to parts by `boundary`, modify text content and assemble new request body `modifiedBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` (it is Spring WebFlux, then I create Mono from this new byte array `Mono.just(byteArray)`).

The problem is body content (images, and maybe other types) may crash.
Is there are a proper way to convert byte[] array into String and back? Maybe something wrong with encoding?

Comment: Strings are text and data isn't that. You can't do what you want. With ISO_8859_1 you can kind of hack around it, at best.